# aws emr pyspark stuck on collect call

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am trying to learn to setup pyspark on aws emr. However, the sample job I am running is stuck in collect api call. I am using emr version 5-30.1.
I dont see any relevant logs associated with this. May be, I am not looking at the right place.

Following is the spark-submit command

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 --conf spark.driver.memory=4g --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.driver.cores=2 --conf spark.logConf=true --py-files s3://cdk_assets/assets/cdk.out/asset.5a391.zip s3://cdk_assets/assets/cdk.out/asset.3ab5bae.py'
```

This is the sample script I am running

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def run():
    print("Sample started")
    spark_session = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("Spark_Sample") \
        .master("yarn") \
        .getOrCreate()
    temp_c = [10, 3, -5, 25, 1, 9, 29, -10, 5]
    rdd_temp_c = spark_session.sparkContext.parallelize(temp_c)
    rdd_temp_k = rdd_temp_c.map(lambda x: x + 273.15).collect()
    print(rdd_temp_k)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

I could see the following exceptions but I am not sure how they are related.
First one is under the node//provision-node/apps-phase//install.stderr

```
2020-09-28 15:30:37,496 ERROR main: Encountered a problem while provisioning
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972)
    at com.amazonaws.emr.node.provisioner.http.JsonHttpClient.doRequest(JsonHttpClient.java:49)
    at com.amazonaws.emr.node.provisioner.platform.EmrPlatformClient.getConfiguration(EmrPlatformClient.java:51)
    at com.amazonaws.emr.node.provisioner.platform.EmrPlatformClient.getConfiguration(EmrPlatformClient.java:43)
    at com.amazonaws.emr.node.provisioner.bigtop.config.PlatformContextProvider.provide(PlatformContextProvider.java:39)
    at com.amazonaws.emr.node.provisioner.workflow.NodeProvisionerWorkflow.work(NodeProvisionerWorkflow.java:97)
    at com.amazonaws.emr.node.provisioner.Program.main(Program.java:30)
```

Second is from yarn node-manager logs

```
2020-09-28 15:34:37,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client (main): Retrying connect to server: ip-10-0-217-37.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.0.217.37:8025. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2020-09-28 15:34:38,250 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client (main): Retrying connect to server: ip-10-0-217-37.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.0.217.37:8025. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2020-09-28 15:34:39,251 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client (main): Retrying connect to server: ip-10-0-217-37.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.0.217.37:8025. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2020-09-28 15:34:39,252 WARN org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client (main): Failed to connect to server: ip-10-0-217-37.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.0.217.37:8025: retries get failed due to exceeded maximum allowed retries number: 10
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:788)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3500(Client.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1381)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1345)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.registerNodeManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.impl.pb.client.ResourceTrackerPBClientImpl.registerNodeManager(ResourceTrackerPBClientImpl.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:346)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.registerNodeManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:637)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:684)
2020-09-28 15:35:09,840 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.security.NMContainerTokenSecretManager (main): Rolling master-key for container-tokens, got key with id 1723617652
2020-09-28 15:35:09,845 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInNM (main): Rolling master-key for container-tokens, got key with id 1930837132
2020-09-28 15:35:09,845 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl (main): NodeLabels sent from NM while registration were rejected by RM. And with message Node Labels {CORE} reported from NM with ID ip-10-0-192-171.us-west-2.compute.internal:8041 was rejected from RM with exception message as : Not all labels being replaced contained by known label collections, please check, new labels=[CORE]
2020-09-28 15:35:09,845 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl (main): Registered with ResourceManager as ip-10-0-192-171.us-west-2.compute.internal:8041 with total resource of <memory:6144, vCores:4>
2020-09-28 15:35:09,846 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl (main): Notifying ContainerManager to unblock new container-requests
2020-09-28 15:35:09,938 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl (Node Status Updater): NM node labels {<CORE:exclusivity=true>} were not accepted by RM and message from RM : Node Labels {CORE} reported from NM with ID ip-10-0-192-171.us-west-2.compute.internal:8041 was rejected from RM with exception message as : Not all labels being replaced contained by known label collections, please check, new labels=[CORE]
```

Can somebody guide me with potential pointers on how to debug this issue further.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you make following changes and let me know what happen? I will convert it into answer if it works. Use this for session building
` spark_session = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("spark sample)\
        .getOrCreate()` 
and submit with `spark-submit  --py-files s3://cdk_assets/assets/cdk.out/asset.5a391.zip s3://cdk_assets/assets/cdk.out/asset.3ab5bae.py'

Comment: Emr uses Yarn by default i guess, Also, do you really need all these configurations as the way you have provided with submit command?

Comment: @A.B It did work. In my trial and error, I could find that what made the  difference was the deployment mode. When I changed it to client from cluster, it started to work. But I am not sure why it is like that. Are you aware of the reason?

Comment: I have converted this info answer and have also tried to answer ypur query, feel free to upvote & accept the answer

Comment: Also, can you let me know, if your worker or driver/master node has IP 10.0.217.37. to which node it belongs?

Answer (score 0):

Emr uses Yarn by default I guess, can you first try the simple session config and spark-submit command to rule out other problem?

Use this for session building

```
 spark_session = SparkSession\ .builder\ .appName("spark sample)\ .getOrCreate()
```

and submit with

```
  spark-submit --py-files s3://cdk_assets/assets/cdk.out/asset.5a391.zip s3://cdk_assets/assets/cdk.out/asset.3ab5bae.py
```

update: why it ran with deploy mode of client

By default spark application runs in client mode, i.e. driver runs on the node where you're submitting the application from.

Similarly, if you use cluster mode, he
“driver” component of spark job will not run on the local machine from which job is submitted. It will run on for example on worker,so you need to have right connections to master(yarn) from there.

As i mentioned in the comment, make sure you really need all the configuration you provided with spark submit command, if not, submit it with required parameters.